# Erro ao executar um comando Flutter

Tags: linux, flutter, terminal

Para testar se o flutter foi corretamente instalando na minha máquina Linux eu escrevi na bash o seguinte comando : `flutter doctor` e recebi a seguinte mensagem de retorno :

> zsh: command not found: flutter

A minha tentativa foi passar o caminho para o SDK do meu Flutter `export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH:/home/gabriel_rc/flutter` , porém não funcionou.

Como posso resolver este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela mensagem de erro você está usando o `zsh` e não o `bash`.
Então edite suas variáveis de ambiente no arquivo `.zshrc` na raíz do seu usuário, se ele não existir, crie com:

```
export PATH=/home/gabriel_rc/flutter/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta ! Uma dúvida : esta linha de código é para ser inserida ao fim do arquivo? eu tentei e não tive êxito

Comment: Em qualquer lugar, desde que não esteja comentada. Eu estou utilizando Mac e não Linux, mas tente conforme o padrão citado nesta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530176/7323067

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado

Comment: @GabrielRibeiroCarneiro Show! Poderia marcar a resposta como aceita então ;)

Answer (score 1):

1) Abra o arquivo .bashrc que está na sua /home/gabriel_rc

2) Adicione esta linha de código por último no arquivo

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/gabriel_rc/flutter/bin"
```

3) Salve as mudanças do arquivo e reinicie a sessão do terminal(só fechar o terminal e abrir novamente)

Veja a documentação [aqui](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/linux#update-your-path) para a instalação linux

Comment: Obg pela resposta. Eu já fiz esse procedimento, porém não funcionou

Comment: Você está colocando o /bin no final do caminho? Vi que você escreveu o caminho apenas até /flutter.

Comment: se encontra assim no momento : export PATH="$PATH:/home/gabriel_rc/flutter/bin"